# Android Scroll View Popup Not working

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview

I am newbie to android. I am trying to implement scrollable popup window on android.

If i make scroll view In my view its shows error **ScrollView can host only one direct child (Details)**

here is my code

```
   private PopupWindow pwindo;

    private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {
// We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) About.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_popup,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout,700,1000, true);
           // pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          //  pwindo.showAsDropDown(layout, 80, 80);

            btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pwindo.dismiss();

        }
    };
```

And My view

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element">
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<ImageButton/>
<ImageButton/>
.
.
.
.


</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding a parent layout (mostly Linearlayout) to ScrollView and assign ID(@+id/popup_element) to that parent layout, instead of assigning ID to ScrollView. And make sure your ScrollView contains only one child layout. So club your other layouts in single LinearLayout and make that layout as child of ScrollView!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Linear Layout as a parent :

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"> 

<TextView/> <TextView/> <TextView/> <ImageButton/> <ImageButton/> . . . .

</ScrollView> 
</linearLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"> as a parent<ScrollView
   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element">
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<ImageButton/>
<ImageButton/>
.
.
.</linearlayout>
.


</ScrollView>

Comment: put scrollview height to wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

Put a LinearLayout inside ScrollView as [you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Layout should look like this

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView/>
      <TextView/>
      <TextView/>
      <ImageButton/>
      <ImageButton/>
   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Place all those views inside `LinearLayout`
and also give little less width and height for popup window

```
pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout,400,400, true);
```

Comment: **ScrollView can host only one direct child** this error should not come if you use my solution

Answer (score 1):

This may help you...

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/popup_element">>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/child">
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <ImageButton/>
    <ImageButton/>
  .
  .
  .
  .

 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Add LinearLayout as a direct child and put the other controls in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Here below you should do it this way!**

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/popup_element">
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <ImageButton/>
    <ImageButton/>
    .
    .
    .
    .


    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nope, ScrollView must contains only one direct child so LinearLayout should be inside ScrollView

Comment: @Kaushik I tried it bro.. but its not helping me too...!!

Comment: well, then update your question...what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

**`ScrollView` is working on `PopupWindow`!**

My problem was due to the fact that the window height of popup was not limited

You can pre-determine the height of layout through the method `View.measure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)`, but it should not be unlimited and the height is less than screen or window then there will be scrolling